# Is there a way to cancel an edit?

Tags: support, editing

I happened to edit a question just as someone else did. Their edit was much more clear, but mine ended up being accepted. Is there a way I can cancel an edit while it's being peer reviewed?

Comment: which post was this on? link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to "cancel" an edit is to use the rollback feature of the post. Peer reviewed edits don't have a way for you to "rollback" since the post hasn't actually been edited.  So to my knowledge there is no way to cancel a peer-reviewed edit.